# git log with line break when exported to text file

Tags: git, line-breaks

How do I add a line break for my custom git log?

```
git log --pretty=tformat:"%ai %s" > log.log
```

I want a line break after `%s`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `%n` as a new line:

```
git log --pretty=tformat:"%ai %s%n" > log.log
```

Comment: I did that and it works when viewed in notepadd++ but it still looks like there is no line break when viewed in notepad

Comment: It didn't work for me as well The issue is that git log separate files with \n only while notepad and \most windows apps use \r\n (CRLF).

If fixed it by running the script posted in my answer below

Answer (score 8):

Pjz's answer is not quite right for Windows, but with a little playing around I got it to work.  The 10 and 13 characters needed to be reversed, and they needed to be in proper hex format:

```
git log --pretty=tformat:"%ai %s%x0D%x0A" >log.log
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that git uses LF as a separator while notepad and most windows application uses CRLF. The following script enabled me to produce a file with all changes.

```
del files.txt >nul 2>nul
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only HEAD > changes.txt
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('type "changes.txt"') do echo %%A >> files.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

The other answers for Windows result in extra 0x0A characters in the file.  Git already appends 0x0A to each log entry, so you just need to add the missing 0x0D:

```
git log --pretty=tformat:"%ai %s%x0D" >log.log
```

Or inside a batch file:

```
git log --pretty=tformat:"%%ai %%s%%x0D" >log.log
```

Answer (score 2):

The quotes will save you - just put the close quote on the next line, like:

```
git log --pretty=tformat:"%ai %s
" >log.log
```

and it should work.

Alternately, under the PRETTY FORMATS heading of `git log --help` it lists:

```
       ·   %m: left, right or boundary mark

       ·   %n: newline

       ·   %%: a raw %
```

Though apparently a 'newline' is a unix newline so on windows you'll want to use the direct hex codes like:

```
git log --pretty=tformat:"%ai %s%x10%x13" >log.log
```

Comment: please see my comment in CoverosGene's answer. On the hand how do I make a next line in command line?

Answer (score 1):

For those making Windows batch files with git remember to convert single % to double %%.
Also add hex for Carriage Return and Line feed

for example

```
git log --pretty=tformat:"%ai %s%x0D%x0A" >log.log
```

converted for window batch file

```
git log --pretty=tformat:"%%ai %%s%x0D%x0A" >log.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation just now, I wanted to add a line break because `cat -e` would mess with the formatting when running the command in a bash script. I had tried the suggestions in this page and others more, but what really solved my problem was just removing `format:`. Typing only `git log --pretty="%H"` adds a normal line break after the last result.